# DynamoDB returns undefined but does log data in console.log(), async issue?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-nodejs

I have a function that gets some data from DynamoDB using docClient.query(). I'm able to retrieve data and print it on console e.g., `console.log(data))`, but if I try to `return data` I always get undefined.

I thought that `function (err,data){ ... }` was a callback of the `query()` function and was hoping it would wait for the value to be available to before returning.

Clearly I'm new with AWS SDK and async functions, couldn't find documentation that used `return` in the way I needed.

I just need the `aliasHasRole` to return the `isAuthorized` JSON so I can use it elsewhere outside the function.

```
function aliasHasRole(an_alias, a_role) {
    const params = {
        TableName: 'xxxxxxx',
        KeyConditionExpression: '#alias= :alias AND #Role= :Role',
        ExpressionAttributeNames: {
            '#alias': 'alias',
            '#Role': 'Role'
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ':alias': an_alias,
            ':Role': a_role,
        },
    };

    docClient.query(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error when attempting table query, see below:\n\n" + 
JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
            return err;
        } else {
            var isAuthorized = data.Count === 1 && data.Items[0].alias === an_alias && data.Items[0].Role === a_role ? true : false;
            console.log(1,'Access', isAuthorized ? 'Granted' : 'Denied', 'for alias "' + an_alias + '".\n');
            return isAuthorized; //always returns undefined
        }
    })
}

console.log(aliasHasRole("fooAlias","barRole")) // returns undefined.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely that's the issue related to asynchronous code. If you are able to use `docClient.query` with *async/await* syntax, then you can wait for its execution and return value according to its result. You can also use *Promise* syntax if it's necessary to know the `err` value (if exists). Then you can also use *resolve/reject* in your function.

Solution with *async/await* syntax:

```
async function aliasHasRole(an_alias, a_role) {
    const params = {
        TableName: 'xxxxxxx',
        KeyConditionExpression: '#alias= :alias AND #Role= :Role',
        ExpressionAttributeNames: {
            '#alias': 'alias',
            '#Role': 'Role'
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ':alias': an_alias,
            ':Role': a_role,
        }
    };
    const data = await docClient.query(params);
    if (!data) return false;
    const isAuthorized = data.Count === 1 && data.Items[0].alias === an_alias && data.Items[0].Role === a_role ? true : false;
    return isAuthorized;
};

aliasHasRole("fooAlias", "barRole").then(console.log).catch(console.log);
```

*UPDATE*

What really helps is making your query a promise with `.promise()` . Then it can be easily executed and handled with then/catch syntax.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! Unfortunately, `data` seems to be undefined always. VS Code is highlighting `await` and says "'await' has no effect on the type of this expression".

Comment: Nevermind, Hlib it works great, you just have to `.promise()` the `docClient.query()`! Is this the right syntax or am I not supposed to do that? Thank you so much for your help. I'll look into resolve/reject.

Comment: @DanielSegura Sure, you're absolutely right! `.promise()` turns your query into promise so that you can easily use then/catch or any other valid syntax to make promise execute and be handled. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/using-promises.html

Comment: Hey I can't thank you enough. Seriously, I've literally spent like 4 hours trying to get this working, I even went through the doc link you sent above and wouldn't click on my brain. I just refactored it into a promise and did something like `.then( (data,err) => { ... }` and seems to be working just fine!

Comment: @DanielSegura Congrats! Happy coding! ;)